# Correct way for converting RGB heatmap image to Grayscale heatmap

Tags: python, colors, rgb

I am trying to convert a RGB heatmap image to grayscale heatmap image. First I thought It was a simple *rgb to grayscale* conversion. But it isn't.

For example, blue color may represent soft things and red color may represent hard things.

[image: RGB heatmap]

Using commonly used simple *rgb to grayscale* conversion method, I found red and blue color has converted to save gray color although they had very different nature of representation.

[image]

But What I want something like this **where blue is deep gray, and red is bright gray**.

[image]

I had searched a lot. Unfortunately I did't find (or maybe I couldn't understand). After reading some article on rgb color model, I have found a way to generate grayscale image. My code is

```
import colorsys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img = mpimg.imread('input_image/abnormal_hi_res.png')
img = img[ : , : , 0:3] # keep only r, g, b channels  

new_image = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))

for y_pos in range(img.shape[0]):
    for x_pos in range (img.shape[1]):

        color = img[y_pos, x_pos]
        r,g,b = color
        h, _, _ = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b) 
        new_image[y_pos, x_pos] = 1.0 - h

plt.imshow(new_image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

But I believe there should exists a good method backed by proven mathematics.
Please help me to find out the correct one for this problem.

Comment: Looks like you just need to write a function that maps the three rgb values to one gray value as you prefer.

Comment: Yes. a function for mapping rgb to gray. You can assume that commonly used heatmap will be used. (for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/heat-map-module-examples/heat-map-color-gradients). I think that will reduce the ambiguity of rgb color to gray mapping.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these links. They have got some good notes on heatmaps and grayscale

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html
https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

*UPDATE

First, you need to convert your BGR image to LUV then convert it to a grayscale image. Use opencv.

Code for converting BGR to LUV in opencv.

`gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)`

[I think it what you are looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcJgl.png)

Comment: Thank you very much. From your attracted image, it seems I am looking for it. But when I am trying to reproduce according your code, I am getting different color.  Would you please share your full working code?