# Correct way of converting rgb diverging heatmap to grayscale in Python

Tags: python, colors, rgb

I am trying to convert a rgb heatmap image to grayscale heatmap image. The problem, however, is that the heatmap was made using a diverging scale (darker colors in both extremes of the scale and lighter colors in the middle).

In my case, the low values are dark blue, while high values are dark red, similar to "seismic" pallete in matplotlib.pyplot).
Any idea on how to proceed?

PS: I have tried some ideas presented in a similar question (link below) but haven't succeeded:

Example pic:
[image]

[Correct way for converting RGB heatmap image to Grayscale heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827622/correct-way-for-converting-rgb-heatmap-image-to-grayscale-heatmap)

Comment: Can you please post the rgb heatmap image?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have posted an example.

Comment: How was the RGB heatmap generated? Do you have any example of of a linear lowest->highest or access to the original gradient? Because that could be used to generate a direct mapping from RGB->value

Comment: Build two scales, one with red-blue and one with grey (same number of element), so you can easily convert one color to the other. Alternative: take red, give it value 255, white: value 128. Interpolate all red by intensity. Do the same with blue, but with blue equal 0. (because you have either blue or red or white, you can easily do it).

Comment: Thanks Giacomo! However, I think there's is a problem with that, and it is the fact that the darker red (which is the highest value) has "less" red than bright red. And the same happens with blue!